# Dot product of Tensors

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

[image]

I have doubt in the last equality. My argument is that since $g_{ik}$ $g^{ik}$ is a scalar but it can be dependent on $x_i$ so its partial derivative w.r.t $x_i$ shouldn't be zero.
It is a scalar but they are not inverse of each other. Because for inverse $g_{ik} g^{ak}$ should be there i.e. both indices shouldn't match. On a side note if it is an inverse then it should give kronecker delta i.e tensor and shouldn't give scalar.
Reference: Padmanabhan's "Gravitation"

Comment: Hi RandomXYZ, please avoid posting images of text and equations.  If the quoted material is needed in order to understand your question, typesetting it yourself is the policy here.

Comment: Okay, sorry I didn't know about this. I will keep in mind in future.

Comment: The future is now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after comment:

When you write $g^{ik}g_{kj}=\delta^i_j$, you actually understand that both matrices are evaluated in the same point:

$$g^{ik}(x)g_{kj}(x)=\delta^i_j$$

This is by definition, and it is valid for every choice of $x\in M$ (where $M$ is the Riemannian/pseudoRiemannian manifold you’re considering). So,  $g^{ik}(x)g_{kj}(x)$ is a constant independent of the point chosen, so its derivative with respect to any coordinate is zero.

This means that either if it appears as its trace $\delta^i_i=dim(M)$  or in its components $\delta^i_j$, its derivative will always be zero.

Comment: Nitpicking a bit: isn't the important property homogeneity, not isotropy? The derivative cares about values at different points, not in different frames.

Comment: You are right, for unknown reasons I was erroneously convinced that the "isotropic" of "isotropic tensor" was not to take literally and covered all possible diffeomorphisms, included mere translations of a constant quantity

Comment: maybe for the Kronecker delta is still true, but I admit that there are much less involved ways to prove that thing

Answer (score 3):

Since $g^{ab}$ is the inverse of $g_{ab}$, we have $g_{ab} g^{bc} = \delta_a {}^c$. But here we have one more contracted index, which is

$$g_{ab} g^{ba} = \delta_a{}^a = n,$$

where $n$ is the dimension of your space. In particular, it is a constant.